# Why my Thymeleaf showing only the last line of the List

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, thymeleaf

I want to show  the top 5 courses with name and booked times.

I have choosed top 5 courses from my Database , and loaded in one List.

Here is my code:

```
                while (rs.next()) 
                {
                CourseBooking cb = new CourseBooking ();     
                List topCourses = new ArrayList();
                cb.setCoursName(rs.getString(1));
                cb.setBookedTimes(rs.getString(2));
                topCourses.add(cb);
                model.addAttribute("topCourses ", topCourses );
                }
```

But when im using "th:each",it is showing only the last line of top 5,and cannot

read the whole List.

```
            <tr th:each="m : ${topCourses }">      
                <td th:text="${m.coursName}"></td>  
                <td th:text="${m.bookedTimes}"></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: You are recreating the ArrayList inside your loop in every iteration step. So in step 1 it will create the ArrayList and add element 1, in step 2 it throws away the previously created list, creates a new one and add the second element.. etc. pp Move the arrayList declaration outside of your loop and only add to it inside it.

Comment: Ohh you are right! It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Per the comment -- you need to move the creation of your list outside the for loop.) Your code should look like this:

```
List topCourses = new ArrayList<CourseBooking>();

while (rs.next()) {
  CourseBooking cb = new CourseBooking ();     
  cb.setCoursName(rs.getString(1));
  cb.setBookedTimes(rs.getString(2));
  topCourses.add(cb);
}

model.addAttribute("topCourses ", topCourses );
```